# How to enable Soft Delete on an existing Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I know how to enable soft delete (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-ovw-soft-delete) via template deployment when creating a KeyVault. How can I turn this feature on on an existing KeyVault that has been deployed without soft delete being enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is of course possible to adjust the template to include the enablement of soft-delete by adding the key-value pair `"enableSoftDelete": true` to the properties section of the KeyVault resource (see also: [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/2018-02-14/vaults)).

If you want to enable it outside the scope of a template deployment it is possible via manipulating the resource e.g. by using PowerShell:

```
$vaultName = "keyVaultName1"

($resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId (Get-AzureRmKeyVault -VaultName $vaultName).ResourceId).Properties | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name "enableSoftDelete" -Value "true"

Set-AzureRmResource -resourceid $resource.ResourceId -Properties $resource.Properties
```

Found here: [Link](https://samcogan.com/protect-azure-keyvault-resources/)